To calculate dew pressure of hydrocarbon mixture by PC-SAFT
I'm trying to use the PC-SAFT (Perturbed-Chain Statistical Associating Fluid Theory) method to calculate the bubble point and dew point pressures of hydrocarbon mixtures, and subsequently plot the PT phase envelope. My calculations for bubble pressure match the experimental data very well. However, when calculating dew pressure at different temperatures, the program fails to converge. I understand that the difference between calculating bubble pressure and dew pressure lies in how the component compositions are determined through fugacity calculations. Therefore, if the bubble pressure calculations are very accurate, it indicates that the internal parameters of PC-SAFT are correct. So why can't the dew pressure be calculated at all?
I have attached the code for calculating dew pressure below.
I'm really hoping someone can offer me some help and advice. Thank you so much!
def cal_VLE_dew_point(temperature, initial_system_pressure, component_mixture,pc_saft_para_dict,component_name,univeral_model_constant=univeral_model_constant):

    composition_liquid = component_mixture.copy()
    composition_vapor = component_mixture.copy()

    def wrapped_cal_pressure(initial_packing_fraction, temperature, component_mixture, pc_saft_para_dict, target_pressure):
        calculated_pressure = cal_pressure(initial_packing_fraction,temperature,univeral_model_constant,component_name, component_mixture, pc_saft_para_dict,boltzmann_constant = 1.3806*10**-23)
        return np.array(calculated_pressure, dtype=np.float64) - target_pressure

    iteration = 0
    error = 100
    vapor_packing_fraction = 10**-10
    liquid_packing_fraction = 0.5
    while (error > 0.00001) and iteration < 300:
        result = least_squares(wrapped_cal_pressure, liquid_packing_fraction, args=(temperature, composition_liquid, pc_saft_para_dict, initial_system_pressure), xtol=1e-12,ftol=1e-12,gtol=1e-12,max_nfev=50000)  
        liquid_packing_fraction = result.x  

        result = least_squares(wrapped_cal_pressure, vapor_packing_fraction, args=(temperature, composition_vapor, pc_saft_para_dict, initial_system_pressure), xtol=1e-12,ftol=1e-12,gtol=1e-12,max_nfev=50000)  
        vapor_packing_fraction = result.x




        fugacity_coefficient_liquid = cal_fugacity(liquid_packing_fraction, temperature, univeral_model_constant,component_name, composition_liquid, pc_saft_para_dict)
        fugacity_coefficient_vapor = cal_fugacity(vapor_packing_fraction, temperature, univeral_model_constant,component_name, composition_vapor, pc_saft_para_dict)


        update_liquid_compostion = {}
        total_composition_liquid = 0

        for i in component_name:
            update_liquid_compostion[i] = fugacity_coefficient_vapor[i]*composition_vapor[i]/fugacity_coefficient_liquid[i]
            total_composition_liquid += update_liquid_compostion[i]

        for k,v in update_liquid_compostion.items():
            update_liquid_compostion[k] = update_liquid_compostion[k]/total_composition_liquid

        composition_liquid = update_liquid_compostion.copy()
        initial_system_pressure = total_composition_liquid * initial_system_pressure
        error = np.abs(total_composition_liquid - 1.0)

        iteration += 1
    dew_point_pressure = cal_pressure(liquid_packing_fraction,temperature, univeral_model_constant,component_name, composition_liquid, pc_saft_para_dict,boltzmann_constant = 1.3806*10**-23)


    return composition_liquid, composition_vapor, dew_point_pressure

